# Global payment gateway "Access token and merchant info do not match" error

Tags: payment-gateway, global-payments-api

I am trying to implement the global payment gateway using REST APIs, able to generate the access key.
Now i am trying to validate the card, but getting
**{
"error_code": "ACTION_NOT_AUTHORIZED",
"detailed_error_code": "40003",
"detailed_error_description": "Access token and merchant info do not match"
}**
error. Access token is proper because, if i enter wrong token getting invalid token error. Also can any one suggest where can i get the global payments REST API logs?

Answer (score 1):

After chatting with the support team, Finally found the solution, it might help to others, In the API Request body there is an "account_name" parameter, seems to be that is case sensitive. Unfortunately no where it is mentioned, even in their examples also it is "Transaction_Processing" only. But the actual value of this account_name parameter is "transaction_processing"

Comment: Thanks for posting this! Their docs are definitely in need of some clean up.

Comment: I'm running into the same error using the .NET SDK